# How to reverse a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas series that must be flipped upside-down before I concatenate it to the main DataFrame.

I can easily flip it with myseries = myseries.iloc[::-1]

But when I attach it to the main DataFrame, it attaches the default series and not the flipped version. Why doesn't the flipped series stay in place?

```
myseries = myseries.iloc[::-1] 
newdf = pd.concat([newdf, myseries], axis=1)
```

**EDIT:**
So my guess is that the index is being flipped as well, and when I concatenate its probably using the index to attach the series. Is there a way to flip the values in the series but leave the index untouched? My index starts at 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because concatenating is based on the index. You can save the original index, and then set the index of the reversed series equal to the original index:

```
myseries_index = myseries.index
myseries = myseries.iloc[::-1]
myseries.index = myseries_index
```

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation looks at the index. So you just need to reverse the index of your series before concatenation. See the following example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], name='b')
s.index = s.index[::-1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('xyz')})
pd.concat([df, s], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.works for me:)

```
myseries = myseries.iloc[:,::-1]
```

example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

 
 
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A', "Student"],
                          [2, 'B', "Tutor"],
                          [3, 'C', "Instructor"]])
                    
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A', "Student"],
                          [2, 'B', "Tutor"],
                          [3, 'C', "Instructor"]])
 
# reversing the dataframe
print("Reversed DataFrame")
dataframe = dataframe.iloc[:,::-1]

dataframe1 = pd.concat([dataframe1,dataframe],axis=1);
print(dataframe1);
```